# How to extract String resource in my code?

Tags: android

When I add the string as parameter like this, everything is OK:

```
mPages[0] = new Page(
                R.drawable.page0,
                "On your return trip from studying Saturn's rings, you hear a distress signal that seems to be coming" +
                        " from the surface of Mars. It's strange because there hasn't been a colony there in years. " +
                        "Even stranger, it's calling you by name: \"Help me, %1$s, you're my only hope.\"",
                new Choice("Stop and investigate", 1),
                new Choice("Continue home to earth", 2));
```

However, when I try to extract the string resource like this, there is an error

```
mPages[0] = new Page(
                R.drawable.page0,
                .getString(R.string.story_page0),
                new Choice("Stop and investigate", 1),
                new Choice("Continue home to earth", 2));
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what error occurs?

Comment: tyr `getResources().getString(R.string.story_page0);`

Comment: It shows ')' expected after "page0"

Comment: @Mohit: I have tried that but the error is still there.

Comment: You've made a typo in line **.getString(R.string.story_page0);** - remove dot before getString and ; at the end

Comment: @PiKos: If I remove the dot, it is required to create getString () method. Sorry the ; at the end is my mistake but the problem is available with the , too

Comment: @Rubit: Ok, it means that your code is outside of Activity/Fragment. In that case you first need to have a Context object. Context has a method getString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use :

```
mPages[0] = new Page(
            R.drawable.page0,
            string.valueOf(R.string.story_page0),
            new Choice("Stop and investigate", 1),
            new Choice("Continue home to earth", 2));
```

and for advice make all your strings like "Stop and investigate" and "Continue home to earth"  in your `String.xml` file

Comment: You mean `.getResources().getString(R.string.story_page0),` ?. As without the `.`, it requires create getResources() method and with the dot it shows the same above problem.

Comment: try to use `string.valueOf(R.string.story_page0)`

Comment: So simple but it works like charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: my pleasure, i update the response please mark it for the others. happy coding :))

Comment: @BOUTERBIATE Oualid: Hi, this works; However, it leads to another problem. In the `R.string.story_page0` I format `%1$s` for being replaced by the input username. By using `string.valueOf`, now I'm struggling with how to replace the formated string.

Comment: You want to remplace this `%1$s` by `string.valueOf(R.string.story_page0)` ?? i don't understand your question ?

Comment: Not, the `%1$s` stored in the string resource like this:  ` <string name="story_page0">\"Help me, %1$s, you\'re my only hope.\"`. I want to replace it with an input username. However by set the value of, it print out exactly the `%1$s` instead of an input username.

Comment: Yes and the old problem happens again, similar to other answer in this post.   It seems that I should take time to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

remove `;` after `.getString(R.string.story_page0)` ands add `,` .it should be

```
mPages[0] = new Page(
            R.drawable.page0,
            getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.story_page0),   //--here
            new Choice("Stop and investigate", 1),
            new Choice("Continue home to earth", 2));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, actually there is the "," instead of ";" in my code too like you said, but the error is still there.

Comment: what are the parameters of you `new Page()` constructor  ?

Comment: @Mohit You can already deduce that from his/her code! It takes `(int, String, Choice, Choice)`, unless `Choice` is a subclass of some class. It is unlikely that it takes four `Object`s.

Comment: `public Page(int imageId, String text, Choice choice1, Choice choice2) {
        mImageId = imageId;
        mText = text;
        mChoice1 = choice1;
        mChoice2 = choice2;
    }`

Comment: @Rubit Look at my answer, I think what you need is the `Context` and a `Resources` object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call `getString`.

You need to get a `Resources` object first and call `getString` on that object.

To get a `Resources` object, you need a `Context`. If your code is placed in a subclass of `Activity` or `Context`, you can just use `this`. For now, I assume you are.

Let's first get a resources by calling:

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

And then we call `getString` to get the string:

```
String s = res.getString();
```

Then you just create your `Page` or whatever:

```
mPages[0] = new Page(
                R.drawable.page0,
                s,
                new Choice("Stop and investigate", 1),
                new Choice("Continue home to earth", 2));
```

Comment: I have thought the same thing and I believe "cannot directly call getString" is my problem. However, as I have page 1,2,3,4,5, etc. and I need to create resource object for every single page. Should I just copy and paste the original String, instead of use string resource?

Comment: @Rubit If you want to localize your app, you should use string resources. If you don't want to localize your app, then not doing so is also fine.